# How can i split the following string based upon double spaces, single spaces, ^, :and |?

Tags: java, arrays, string

How can i split the following string based upon double spaces, single spaces, `^`, `:` and `|`

`0  0  0  0  0 :  0  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  0  0 :  0  0  0  0  0 |  0  0 ^  0  0  0 :  0  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  0  0 :  0  0  6  4  5 |  1  1  8  7  1 :  9  1  6  5 16 |  0  0  0  0  0 :  1  4 25  0`

Comment: For what purpose? What do you expect as the result?

Comment: You forgot to put what you tried in the question.

Comment: By *"based upon"*, do you mean you just need to split on any of them, or do you also need to know which separator you split on? Also, what should happen for 3 or more spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting the string like below

```
String abc = "0  0  : 25 ^  2 : 1 | 0";
String[] stringarr = abc.split("[ ]+|\\:+|\\^+|\\|");
```

Comment: I need array of digits without spaces, : and |